# Xcode 7.2 - clang: error: no such file or directory:

Tags: ios, xcode

I keep trying to run my Xcode project titled 'Simple Calculator' and it keeps giving me the following error,

> clang: error: no such file or directory:
>   '/Users/computerscienceyr1/Desktop/Simple Calculator/Simple
>   Calculator/ViewController.m'

Here is a screenshot of the whole issue [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmIPv.png).
Each time I create a 'Simple Calculator' Directory, the error extends into: '/Users/computerscienceyr1/Desktop/Simple Calculator/Simple Calculator/Simple Calculator/ViewController.m' and goes on and on.

```
                                    **UPDATED**
```

This is what happens when double clicked [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGzs4.png).

Targets> Build Phases> Compile Sources - File exists.

Removed ViewController.m and others again. No changes occurred.

Comment: remove ViewController add again!

Comment: None of your source files exist on disk.  What happens when you double-click on them within Xcode?

Comment: goto targets->build phases ->Compile sources check your file if it is not existing then add it again.

Answer (score -1):

Try this: open the .pbxproj file, search for the file name and delete the rows where it appears, then add the file again to your project.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31024956/xcode-7-no-such-file-or-directory) may help you as well.

Comment: What does that achieve that cannot be done inside Xcode by simply pressing `Delete`?