# No such file or directory XCODE 7

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7

I'm trying to test my app into the simulator but I have this error:

> "No such file or directory"

This is just the last word.

All the error is this:

> /Users/g4b0cu4dr05_c4rd3n4s/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CityLines-desdmmzxgmoemhavllwykbcogetw/Build/Intermediates/CityLines.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CityLines.build/Script-1B1FAC6D1C0E6D02003951B3.sh: line 2: /usr/local/bin/carthage: No such file or directory

Comment: try cleaning your project with cmd + shift + k

Comment: Or simply 'rm -rf /Users/g4b0cu4dr05_c4rd3n4s/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CityLines-desdmmzxgmoemhavllwykbcogetw'

Comment: didn't work :C (but thank u guys)

Comment: Check this > http://stackoverflow.com/a/42089897/3024579

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer was pretty easy: I just have to reinstall the pod file and the Carthage file and everything works nice.

Comment: Brother I posted my answer according to what you posted the question and also it's error.I gave you points which what other have given answer or posted answer.That's the reason why I also gave links but I don't know why people downvoted my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Do the following things

```
  1.Close the XCode
  2.Delete the app from simulator
  3.Quite XCode
  4.Go to library ->developer->XCode->Derived Data->Then delete your above script..... File or folder.
  5.Now finally clean and run the application.
```

below reference

[Xcode- 7: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31024956/xcode-7-no-such-file-or-directory)

[Xcode suddenly stopped running project on hardware: "Could not launch xxx.app: .. No such file.."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11456312/xcode-suddenly-stopped-running-project-on-hardware-could-not-launch-xxx-app)

Comment: Did you go through the above links?

Comment: Yep, and i try it again and keep failing

Comment: Tell me the reason for down voting my answer